# Refreshing data in storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I replaced data in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket by uploading the file with the same name and overwriting it. But when I query the file in Big Query then it still shows the old data. How can I get Big Query to fetch the file again and overwrite the data?

Comment: I mean, is there a way to upload files without having to create new tables in Big Query every time?

Comment: Do you have [object versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#list-gsutil) or [object lifecycle management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) enabled on the bucket? Are you [querying the data in Cloud Storage using temporary or permanent tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage)? What exactly are you using (Cloud Console, bq command,  API, Code Sample? What is your exact workflow?

Comment: How are you downloading the file?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! When I created the tables in Big Query I changed them from Internal Tables to External Tables. Then the query fetches the data from GCS every time and when I change that file in GCS the changes reflect.